# Download script in php

Tags: php, wordpress, download

I need to download .sql file in a folder. I have a button named download. And button has it's own value.
 ie.

```
(sql filename   action)
(1.sql   -------       download,
2.sql     --------     download)
```

when clicking on download button

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['download'])){echo $_REQUEST['download']; //result either 1.sql or 2.sql}
1.sql,2.sql are in the same folder in which my download.php file is placed.
```

This work is for my word press site.My need is to download 1.sql or 2.sql to my computer when corresponding button is clicked.

ie

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['download'])){download file.(ie.download $_REQUEST['download'])}.
```

Comment: Try `Header("Location: filename.php")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just want to download the file it's this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$yourfilename."\"");
readfile($pathtoyourfile.$filename);
```

Comment: I am working on my word press site. So when i write this code  "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" msg is shown.

Comment: Yes, because you're not allowed to output anything before the header() call. You can try to put this code in an extra php-file with no output and then use a link to open the extra php-file from your wordpress site.

Comment: Well you can create a file in the wordpress folder for example...named "download.php" and then put this code into download.php - The values could be set by GET or POST for example and then you just take a link to download.php?file=1 - and in download.php you ask for if($_GET['file'] == 1) { $yourfilename = "sql1.sql"; $pathtoyourfile..... }

Comment: Not very safe approach when you are working in wp-admin plugins. There should be also user role validation in the other file.